# Observables binding

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, observable

So, I'm currently developing an app using *MVVM design pattern* that has a ***SignUpViewController*** screen and respectively a ***SignUpViewModel***.

In my *SignUpViewController* I have two textfields (email, password), and of course a 'Sign Up' button. On the other hand, inside SignUpViewModel I have some observers, now.. the one that is making me doubt is an observable of type bool.

I'll share down below how I've declared my Bindable class:

```swift
import UIKit

class Bindable<T> {
    var value: T? {
        didSet {
            observer?(value)
        }
    }
    
    var observer: ((T?) -> ())?
    
    func bind(observer: @escaping (T?) -> ()) {
        self.observer = observer
    }
    
}
```

In my ViewModel I have 2 observables:

```swift
var errorMessage = Bindable<String>()
var shouldPresentError = Bindable<Bool>()
```

- ***'errorMessage':*** gets set a String that tells about the problem, and passes it with binding to a variable of *SignUpViewController* also called *'errorMessage'*, so it can later present the alert when 'shouldPresentError' changes to *true*.
- ***'shouldPresentError':*** gets a Bool, in *case of true* it presents a UIAlertController inside *SignUpViewController*, in *case of false* it does nothing.

Imagine a user tries to sign up with a non valid email address, so in this case:

1. *'errorMessage'* gets set a message like *"Non valid email address, please try again."*
2. *'shouldPresentError'* gets set to true and displays a UIAlertController inside *SignUpViewController*.

Then, imagine the same user immediately after tries to sign up using another non valid email address...

Will *'shouldPresentError'* display another UIAlertController?? Although it didn't change? (because it got set to *'true'* in the previous step). 
Or should I do this every time I want to set *'shouldPresentError'* to *true*?: (so it changes)

```swift
shouldPresentError.value = false
shouldPresentError.value = true
```

Comment: I wouldn't use a boolean at all.  I would use an optional error message.  If it is non-nil, display the alert.  When you dismiss the alert, set the error message back to `nil.`  You simply observe the error message and display an alert when it isn't `nil`

Comment: Yes, you are right. I'll change that now, thanks Paul. But suppose that I still need to use that boolean, would I have to make it change every time? Or will it bind every time I set that variable to true or false no matter if it's changing or not? @Paulw11

Comment: Also... how do you make text have that grey background in comments? As in 'nil'